# unity3d - raycasting world space UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, virtual-reality, daydream

I need some help with raycasting UI with Daydream. As there are only a demo for gameObjects (cubes), I want to know I can handle UI elements. The UI elements should react as usual, I mean highlighted and so on. The posts in [How to use Graphic Raycaster with WorldSpace UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087609/how-to-use-graphic-raycaster-with-worldspace-ui) were helpful, but completely.

I used DrawRay to see where my pointer is actually going through and it works good. But no log message is created.

```
 void Update()
  {
      Quaternion ori = GvrController.Orientation;
      Vector3 vector = ori * Vector3.forward;
      Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, vector * 100000, Color.green);
      PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(null);
      pointerData.position = vector;
      Debug.Log(vector);
      List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
      EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerData, results);
      if (results.Count > 0)
      {
          Debug.Log(results[0]);
      }
  }
```

Canvas (World Space) and Button is created as useal and not modified.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I see two problems :

- I think you should use `PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);` insted of `PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(null);`
- Also `PointerEventData.position` is a **Vector2** and not a **Vector3** : you should try `pointerData.position = new Vector2(Screen.width * 0.5f, Screen.height * 0.5f);`

As a side note you can use `graphicRaycaster.Raycast(pointerData, results);` where *graphicRaycaster* is public and you assign it the **GraphicRaycaster** component of you **Canvas**.

Comment: Thanks @Kardux for the tips. But unfortenately it does not work. 1. How should the thing with the **Vector2** and the `Screen` work? I don't need screen sizes, but orientation from the controller. `vector` output is (-0.5, 0.0, 0.9) and `pointerData.position` is (-0.5, 0.0) - can that work? 2. I added the **GraphicRaycaster** component to my parent Canvas and used `public GraphicRaycaster graphicRaycaster`, but not log entry at all... any other idea? Do i need a GUICamera?

Comment: @fmielke My bad about the **Vector2** thing including Screen sizes : in my case I always use the middle of the "screen" to raycast against UI (this way the user simply look at the UI to activate it). By giving a **Vector2** a **Vector3** value you simply don't consider the _z_ value (this is why you get (-0.5, 0.0)). In your case I would raycast normally using `Physics.Raycast` against a "ghost wall" placed where your UI is and then use `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint` to get the screen _x_ and _y_ coordinate to set `pointerData.position`.

Comment: I actually "just" need the gameObject behaviour from 

    `RaycastHit hitInfo;
         if (Physics.Raycast(Vector3.zero, vector, out hitInfo))
         {
             Debug.Log("HIT a gameObject");
         }`

But only for UI :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this useful method:

```
Vector3 CurrentRaycastResultWorldPosition = GvrPointerInputModule.Pointer.CurrentRaycastResult.worldPosition;
```

Answer (score -1):

According your question raycasting world space UI ,if you are using google cardbard or daydream than you should try to attach script gvrgraphicphysics raycaster to UI canvas.